# Buttons in QGraphicsView/ QGraphicsScene not painting correctly

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

When I put buttons inside a scene and inside a QGraphicsView, the region to the right of the button incorrectly turn gray.

[image]

I can reproduce this in Windows and Linux. Are there any tricks to get rid of this unwanted feature?

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene,
                             QPushButton, QLabel)
from PyQt5.QtCore import (Qt, QRectF)
from PyQt5 import QtCore


class MyView(QGraphicsView):
    
    def __init__(self, parent = None):

        super(MyView, self).__init__(parent)
              
        self.button1 = QPushButton('Button1')
        self.button1.setGeometry(-60, -60, 80, 40)
        self.button2 = QPushButton('Button2')
        self.button2.setGeometry(10, 10, 80, 40)
        version  = 'PYQT_VERSION_STR: ' + QtCore.PYQT_VERSION_STR + '\n'
        version += 'QT_VERSION_STR: ' + QtCore.QT_VERSION_STR + '\n'
        self.label = QLabel(version)
        self.label.setGeometry(-100, 80, 160, 80)
        
        self.setScene(QGraphicsScene())
        self.scene().addWidget(self.button1)
        self.scene().addWidget(self.button2)
        self.scene().addWidget(self.label)
        
        self.scene().setSceneRect(QRectF(-150, -150, 300, 300))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = MyView()
    widget.show()
    

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: @eyllanesc. Question updated with version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a widget is added to a graphics scene, its proxy uses the `minimumSizeHint()` of the widget as the minimum size for its geometry, no matter if you resize the widget to a smaller size (I don't know if it's a bug or it's done by design).

This has the following result:

- you cannot set a geometry for the proxy smaller than the minimum size [hint] of the source widget;
- resizing the widget to a size smaller than the minimum [hint] will only resize the widget, but the proxy will still use that minimum size [hint];

For example, QPushButton has a minimum size hint that is about 80x30 (the actual values depend on the style and font in use), so even if you resize the button to a smaller size, its proxy will still be 80x30.

To avoid that, you can manually set the minimum size of the widget to reasonable values, or subclass the widget and override [`minimumSizeHint()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#minimumSizeHint-prop).